How to drop first n rows in pandas based on condition leaving the rest of dataframe intact
How to drop first n rows, when I don't know how many, based on condition from the first data row in a pandas dataframe, leaving the rest of dataframe intact?
Say, I would like to drop all first n rows in the following example based on what is the first recorded second. The number of timestamps is not constant.
Code:
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
# sample dataframe
d = {(0) : [pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')])[0] 
                            for s in ['2001-12-23 01:23:59',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:23:59',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:23:59',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:24:00',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:24:00',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:24:01',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:24:02',
                                      '2001-12-23 01:24:02'
                                      ]],
                            (1) : [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
                            }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# obtain first second from timestamp column
sec_1 = df1[0].head(1).dt.second

I know how to filter the whole timestamp column, I am struggling with filtering out as described.
I was looking at concat and iloc, but 'removed statement here'.
Edit:
More clarification.
I need to drop first lines of the above sample dataframe based on value of seconds in the first timestamp, here 59 but can be any other number of seconds. Being a timestamp, it is never known before being created, and can be of any value between 00 and 59. Additionally, it is not known how many the very same timestamps within the very same second will be created.
Hence, in the above sample dataframe I have 3 timestamps with the same number of seconds. Could be 6, could be 31, never known.
Current sample dataframe:
                        0   1
    0 2001-12-23 01:23:59  10
    1 2001-12-23 01:23:59  11
    2 2001-12-23 01:23:59  12
    3 2001-12-23 01:24:00  13
    4 2001-12-23 01:24:00  14
    5 2001-12-23 01:24:01  15
    6 2001-12-23 01:24:02  16
    7 2001-12-23 01:24:02  17

My desired outcome is a dataframe like so:
                        0   1
    3 2001-12-23 01:24:00  13
    4 2001-12-23 01:24:00  14
    5 2001-12-23 01:24:01  15
    6 2001-12-23 01:24:02  16
    7 2001-12-23 01:24:02  17

Where later I can drop nan's, reindex etc.

"based on what is the first recorded second"... based in what way?  When posting an example like this, you should include what your desired output is.

Also, iloc is not deprecated; returning a tuple from a callable in iloc is.

Thanks for claryfying.

IIUC you can do:
mask = df[0] > df[0].iat[0]
print(df[mask])

Prints:
                    0   1
3 2001-12-23 01:24:00  13
4 2001-12-23 01:24:00  14
5 2001-12-23 01:24:01  15
6 2001-12-23 01:24:02  16
7 2001-12-23 01:24:02  17


mask = df1.iloc[0,0].second != df1[0].dt.second maybe?  Sort of hard to determine OP exact problem.

Both solutions work.
Thanks everybody involved for help :)

so first find the index of the first row that meets your condition, you can use .idxmax(), then you can use  .iloc() to slice the dataframe from the index onwards and reassign it. for example if you want to drop rows until the first occurrence of a certain second in the timestamp column, you can do df1 = df1.iloc[df1[0].dt.second.idxmax():]. This will retain all rows from the index of the first occurrence of that second onwards.

Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work on the above sample dataset.

@chairman's_cat one cannot answer your question without guessing what you want. Make things easier, be explicit: clearly explain the logic, and provide the exact expected output given your current input.

Edited with more clarification.
